# Multiple tag manager using matomo

Tags: javascript, analytics, matomo, piwiktracker

Need solution for the following

Need to configure multiple tag manager from different domain, have tried many thing but nothing seems like working

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var _mtm = _mtm || [];
_mtm.push({'mtm.startTime': (new Date().getTime()), 'event': 'mtm.Start'});

var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src='{container 1 from domain ABC}'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);

var d1=document, g1=d1.createElement('script'), s1=d1.getElementsByTagName('script')[1];
g1.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g1.defer=true; g1.src='{container 2 from domain xyz}'; s1.parentNode.insertBefore(g1,s1);


var _paq = _paq || [];
</script>
```

If we use the above code then either the first or the second piwik.php will be called.

Also is there a way to implement tracking code from one domain and a tag manager from another domain?

Thanks